# Another universe due to a rogue wave fluctuation

Tags: cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

Let us consider our Universe at its heat death state, and the rogue wave phenomenon that is due to improbable superposition of small waves. Is it possible that a rogue wave-like quantum fluctuation can transfer the state of maximum entropy of Universe into a state of very low entropy, i.e., a new Big Bang?

The Universe is a closed system where energy can be recycled in myriad of ways. The ever-present quantum fluctuations break down structures, but an unexpected fluctuation can consentrate the energy.

Comment: How is 'Another universe' linked to ours, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's exactly that scenario is mentioned in wiki, on [universe heat death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) :

> It is suggested that, over vast periods of time, a spontaneous entropy decrease would eventually occur via the Poincaré recurrence theorem thermal fluctuations, and fluctuation theorem. Through this, another universe could possibly be created by random quantum fluctuations or quantum tunnelling in roughly
> ${\large 10^{10^{10^{56}}}}$ years.

Although in such year amount literally anything can happen.

Comment: Well, you can't watch even your face without some tooling, like mirrors, cameras, etc. And most of modern science observations are not verifiable in day-to-day humans domestic life. But that does not make science less powerful.